# How can I effectively store and manage data related to quarters in a year for competency levels?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, rest, architecture

I have an architectural question about how to properly store data for future use. In general, I have a list of competencies, for example, developer, tester, manager, etc., and each competency has a level, for example, junior, middle, or senior.

We need to develop a page where there will be a competence switch, and when we click on a competency, we get the salary limit for each level of competence. For example, a photos
(In excel the exactly how it should look like and in another photo i display a competencies. Like switch between them and we have another salaries).

[image]

[image]

**So here is the main question, how to store data for quarters and levels? I have a guess that I need to store quarters in the map. But then my Competency entity should look like:**

```
@Entity
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Audited
@TypeDef(
        name = "pgsql_enum",
        typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Competency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private Level level;

    @Type( type = "json" )
    private HashMap<String, Integer> salaryCap;
    
    // Should I add year? because i need to have ability to change salary caps for the next years. 

}
```

**Here is Level class**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum Level {

  TRAINEE("Trainee"),
  JUNIOR("Junior"),
  INTERMEDIATE("Intermediate"),
  SENIOR("Senior"),
  EXPERT("Expert"),
  TL("Tech lead");

  private final String name;

  public static final Map<String, Level> LEVELS = Stream.of(values())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Level::getName, k -> k));

}
```

In the frontend, I have tsx/typescript files. So I need to know if is this a good approach for this case or if I have a better solution for it.

Comment: By the way, the [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library provides classes for `Quarter` and `YearQuarter`. These interoperate with the *java.time* classes.

Comment: In your second paragraph, what are we switching? What photos? You’ve lost me there.

Comment: @BasilBourque. I have a list of competencies(Developer, tester, manager). When we click Developer I need to have a table with the salary for this competency. when i switch to tester then I need a table with the salary for tester for every quarter. I hope this is clearer. about photo: the first picture is how the should look table with salaries. and in the second switcher of competencies which will show these tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an 1x4 array for each individual employee and store the quarter competence.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Some example code would improve this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the table and have independent enums for each type of values.This will help you easily modify if we have new role or levels.

```
enum Competency{
    DEV,TEST,MANAGER
}
  enum Level {
    TRAINEE, JUNIOR, INTERMEDIATE, SENIOR, EXPERT, TL;
 }
 enum Quater{
    q1,q2,q3,q4
 }
 @Getter
 @Setter
 //@IdClass(DbRecordExcludingMaxvalue.class)//if using jpa/hibernate 
 class DbRecord {
    Integer year;
    Quater quater;
    Competency competency;
    Level level;
    Double maxValue;

     public DbRecord(Integer year, Quater quater, Competency competency, Level level) {
         this.year = year;
         this.quater = quater;
         this.competency = competency;
         this.level = level;
     }
 }

 class RecordHelper{

    public static List<DbRecord> getAllCombination(Integer year){
        //validation for year
        ArrayList<DbRecord> dbRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Quater quater : Quater.values()) {
            for (Competency competency : Competency.values()) {
                for (Level level : Level.values()) {
                    dbRecords.add(new DbRecord(year,quater,competency,level));
                }
            }
        }
        return dbRecords;
     }

 }

public class DesignCompetencyQuater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DbRecord> list = RecordHelper.getAllCombination(2023);

        Predicate<DbRecord> yearFilter = dbRecord -> dbRecord.getYear() ==2023;
        Predicate<DbRecord> competencyFilter = dbRecord -> dbRecord.getCompetency() == Competency.DEV;
        Predicate<DbRecord> level = dbRecord -> dbRecord.getLevel() == Level.TRAINEE;
        Predicate<DbRecord> quater = dbRecord -> dbRecord.getQuater() == Quater.q1;

        Predicate<DbRecord> filter = Stream.of(yearFilter, competencyFilter,level)
                                            .reduce(Predicate::and)
                                            .get();

        List<DbRecord> dev_Trainee_AllQuaters_2023 = list.stream()
                                                    .filter(filter)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // since in ui you can pass the entire filtered list to display in pivot table format

        Predicate<DbRecord> filter2 = Stream.of(yearFilter, competencyFilter,quater)
                                        .reduce(Predicate::and)
                                        .get();

        List<DbRecord> dev_q1_2023 = list.stream()
                                    .filter(filter2)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    }
}
```

To avoid splitting of each type of enum values across same table you could have different lookup tables for each enums.

[image]